# Split a string into multiple variables

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a string in the following form :

`"425x344"`

Now I'd like to resolve first and second numbers from this string as two separate variables. How can I do this ? I've created this regex:

`regex = re.compile(r"^(\d+x\d+)")`

to check if the string form is proper. But what next ?

Comment: Use `...$` and `.match` (or `^...$` and `.search`) to make sure the whole sting is consumed. As of now, both ways of running the regex accept `1x1foo`.

Comment: And using `$` will accept `1x1\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're filtering it with a regex, you can just do

```
a, b = map(int, s.split('x'))
res = a * b
```

If you're planning on multiplying, it can be done in one line:

```
res = eval(s.replace('x', '*'))
```

or

```
res = (lambda x, y: x * y)(*map(int, s.split('x')))
```

With an import and one line, this can be done with

```
import operator

res = operator.mul(*map(int, s.split('x')))
```

You'll have to profile them to see which is faster.

Comment: Nevermind. It's because I was missing a Parenthesis. Being a Chimpanzee, I get discriminated against so much that I've gotten a little sensitive. Thanks to the anonymous downvoter for the helpful  error message. You should get a job as a C compiler.

Comment: ... or a Python compiler ... `Syntax Error: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 5):

`a, b = '425x344'.split('x')`

Comment: Although that will give you the numbers as strings.

Comment: The OP just said he/she wants it in two separate variables.

Comment: a, b = [int(n) for n in '425x344'.split('x')]

Comment: @Rafael, `int`, `str` and the other builtin class constructors are one of the few cases where `map` is better than a list comprehension. The more you know.

Comment: @aaronasterling nice to know, but what's the rationale?

Comment: @Simone, Every time I've tested it, it's significantly faster.

Comment: although your solution is the easiest, aarona's gives possibilities to learn something new, and what more set the types of variables. Still thanks for reminding about split :)

Comment: On the other hand, `[int(n) for n in '23x34'.split('x')]` translates without change to Python 3 where `map` becomes a generator and needs to be used as `list(map(...))` which might slow things down.

Comment: @aaronasterling I believe you, but is there an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
regex = re.compile(r"^(\d+)x(\d+)")
```

Then use regex.match(my_string) to get the MatchObject out, and you can use match.group(1) and match.group(2) to get the variables out.

Comment: `group(0)` returns the full match text. You want `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean "values", or "literals". 425 is not typically a valid name for a variable, which tend to have symbolic names.

If you change your regular expression to capture the numbers separately:

```
regex = re.compile(r"^(\d+)x(\d+)")
```

you can then use code like this:

```
str = "425x344"
mo = regex.search(str)
if mo != None:
  print "%s=%d" % (str, int(mo.group(1)) * int(mo.group(2)))
```

to compute the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do it with re, http://effbot.org/zone/xml-scanner.htm might be worth a read. It shows how to properly split each argument in a expr with re

```
import re

expr = "b = 2 + a*10"

for item in re.findall("\s*(?:(\d+)|(\w+)|(.))", expr):
    print item
```